# Override Data sent by WooCommerce with data from Gravity Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

So I am using Wordpress with WooCommerce, WooCommerce Subscriptions and Gravity Forms. The problem I am having is that the product is a variable product, with an attribute and variations. WooCommerce is displaying the attribute on the main screen and does not update when the form is filled out. The attribute corresponds to how often the customer would like to pay (IE: Every Month, Every Other Month, Every 3 Months, Every 6 Months, and Once a Year) What happens is that there is a drop down above the form, the form does not display until you choose an option. Once you choose one the form pops up. I choose 6 months. In the form I ask how often you want to be billed if you choose monthly and it does not change or affect the attribute at all. IE I choose 12 months because I changed my mind, the cart will show 6 months when I check out and thats what I will get billed for. I need someone to point me in the right direction to make this happen. All of the Values in the Gravity form match the ones in WooCommerce Attributes. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can't seem to figure this one little bug out.

The site can be viewed at http://petpakz.com/product/petpakz-testing/

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I finally solved this. Here is the working code that changes the Attribute from WooCommerce via whats selected in the gravityform

```
function mydesign_add_billing_js() {
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//BRONZE//
$('#choice_6_18_0').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('1 Month');
});
$('#choice_6_18_1').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('3 Months');
});
$('#choice_6_18_2').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('6 Months');
});
$('#choice_6_18_3').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('12 Months');
});
//SILVER//
$('#choice_6_24_0').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('1 Month');
});
$('#choice_6_24_1').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('3 Months');
});
$('#choice_6_24_2').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('6 Months');
});
$('#choice_6_24_3').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('12 Months');
});
//GOLD//
$('#choice_6_25_0').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('1 Month');
});
$('#choice_6_25_1').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('3 Months');
});
$('#choice_6_25_2').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('6 Months');
});
$('#choice_6_25_3').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('12 Months');
});
//BI-Monthly//
$('#choice_6_8_1').on('click', function() {
    $('#select-plan-type').val('Bi-Monthly');
});
});
</script>
<?php
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mydesign_pre_get_posts_query' );
```